# Como posso verificar o fim de uma stream do youtube?

Tags: youtube

Eu sei que usando a API do youtube eu posso verificar quando um vídeo termina. Mas e então uma stream? O código é o mesmo?

Este é um exemplo do código que uso

```
<iframe width="100%" style="height: 200px !important;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=CHANNEL_ID&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;autoplay=1&controls=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Talvez este documento possa ajudar: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Retrieving_video_information

Comment: @dvd Vou explorar essa opção!